# SWT Widgets Input Validation

Tags: java, validation, text, swt

I'm stuck really

I need to validate user input in Text widgets. I don't need data binding i don't need observable values for models and targets all i need is just to get the text entered by the user and validate it just to see if it is empty or not.

I also want the user to get an error message stating the issue using a decorator.

Is there any easy straight forward way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Text.addVerifyListener` to add a verify listener class, the single method in this class is:

```java
public void verifyText(VerifyEvent event);
```

The `VerifyEvent` contains fields for the text and the start and end positions of the change. You set the `doit` flag to `false` to prevent a change from being accepted.

Comment: I did that but, the text widget gets blocked is i try to change the value.

Comment: Use Display.asyncExec if you want to change UI objects from inside the listener